# C++ concept equivalent of std::decay?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm new to concepts. As far as I understand it [the concept library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts) lists all the available std concepts. Yet there seems nothing like std::decay? Compare the following general use case where I want to restrict the input to a method to the class specialization type:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:16),source:%27%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%23include+%3Cconcepts%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T%3E%0Astruct+some_struct%0A%7B%0A++++template+%3Ctypename+U,+typename+%3D+std::enable_if_t%3Cstd::is_same_v%3Cstd::decay_t%3CU%3E,+T%3E%3E%3E%0A++++void+do_something(U+obj)+%7B%0A++++++++return+%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++some_struct%3Cint%3E+obj%3B%0A%0A++++obj.do_something(0)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:60.71553228621291,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:39.28446771378708,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <concepts>

template <typename T>
struct some_struct
{
    template <typename U, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<U>, T>>>
    void do_something(U obj) {
        return ;
    }
};

int main()
{
    some_struct<int> obj;

    obj.do_something(0);
}
```

How can I accomplish this with concepts?

Comment: `std::same_as<T, std::decay_t<U>>`?

Comment: @user17732522 I know its a contrived example.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you, is that hinting that templates and concepts can always be used interchangeably?

Comment: Pretty much.  concepts are a king of syntactic sugar added to make meta programing easier.

Answer (score 6):

You could add a concept like:

```cpp
template <typename U, typename T>
concept DecaysTo = std::same_as<std::decay_t<U>, T>;
```

Which would allow:

```cpp
template <DecaysTo<T> U>
void do_something(U&&);
```

---

Note that this only really makes sense when using a forwarding reference. In the original example where the parameter type is `U`, `std::decay_t<U>` is just `U`, so `DecaysTo<T>` reduces to `std::same_as<T>`. It still correct, just unnecessarily involved.

Comment: *"`std::decay_t<U>` is just `U`"*. only if we let deduction happens, it would be possible to do a call like `obj.do_something<int&>(i);` ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Is it idomatic to write concepts in pascal case?

Comment: @glades: naming convention in std is snake_case everywhere (except some MACROs). Most naming conventions I see outside of std/boost use incompatible/other conventions... (apply to concept, but even to class/function/... names).

Comment: @glades FYI, PascalCase was used in the C++ working draft in early days, but these names were rewritten in snake_case later, see [P1754R1](https://wg21.link/p1754r1).